# What is a replacement for devmem write in a bash script?

Tags: bash, memory, write

I can use the dd command to read a memory address (ex: 0x400):

```
dd if=/dev/mem count=4 bs=1 skip=$(( 0x400 ))
```

But how would I write a value to physical address (ex: 0x400)?  I tried this:

```
function T_WRITE2 {
  printf $1 | dd of=/dev/mem count=4 bs=1 skip=$(( 0x400 ))
}
```

But I get the error:

```
dd: 'standard input': cannot skip to specified offset
```

(How do I get input to not skip any but the output to skip to the address to write?)

Comment: Remember that _promiscuous `/dev/mem`_ has been widely turned off for about 16 years, now.

Comment: Not necessarily.  It all depends, from factors not stated in this question and not givens here.  https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/532381/5132

Answer (score 2):

`skip` skips bytes in the input; to write to a specific offset in the output, you need to “seek”, using the `seek` option:

```
dd of=/dev/mem count=4 bs=1 seek=$((0x400))
```